# How identifier code should be defined in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing

I want to identify documents with code - index.
For example:

```
// user
{
  code: 1,
  name: "John"
}
```

Now `code` should be numeric or string? Also, should it be randomly created or auto increasing?

If auto increasing, could be done starting from a specific number?

How to do this functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not identify users the usual way, via `_id` field?

Comment: Sometimes I have nested documents which I want to give an ID for them too

Comment: You can use ObjectId there too.